# How to Parse JSON to Object in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The ModelClass is define as shown below:

```
class Comment{
      String? id;
      String? pId;
      String? text;
        factory Comment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
        Comment(
          id: json["id"] as String?,
          pId: json["text"] as String?,
          text: json["text"] as String?,
       );
         Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
          "id": id,
          "pId": pId,
          "text": text,
    }
```

The Dto ModelClass has Comment and List of Comment(dynamic) properties as shown below. Please what is wrong with the fromJson and toJson for this class.

```
class MyDto{
  Comment? comment;
  List<dynamic>? reply; // e.g List<Comment>? reply
  
 factory MyDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyDto(
    reply: json["reply"] as List<dynamic>?,
    comment: Comment.fromJson(json['comment'])
  );
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "comment": comment,
    "reply": jsonEncode(reply),
  };
}
```

The http endpoints is as follows:

```
static Future<List<MyDto>> fetchData() async {
    Response response = -----
    List<dynamic> body;
    late List<MyDto> items;
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(body);
      items = body.map((dynamic item) => MyDto.fromJson(item)).toList();
    }
    return items;
  }
```

I have NoSuchMethodError: Class _Map<String, dynamic> has no instant getter id for items[index].reply[i].id from the List property in MyDto. Please how do I solve this error? Check my MyDto Class and fetchData() method.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement a `Reply` class and use `Reply.fromJson(json['reply'])`, so `items[index].reply` still has type `Map` ,therefore you couldn't call `reply.id`.

Maybe you were meant to use `items[index].reply[i]['id']`?